# wakeonlan and etherwake don't work

Tags: linux, wake-on-lan

My goal is to wake up my PC.

I have connected my Raspberry Pi directly through LAN to my PC. I have installed `etherwake` and `wakeonlan`, and both commands failed.

Well, actually it didn't really fail, on the contrary: it said it succeeded but my PC was still off and sleepy!

How I have found the mac address of my PC:

[image: Network Connection Details]

Also rechecked with:

[image: screenshot showing terminal with arp output]

I tried those two commands:

```
 sudo wakeonlan <my mac address>
```

Outputs:

```
 Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9 with 00:25:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

and I get my console back (without anything happening),

and

```
 sudo etherwake <my mac address>
```

didn't work. I got my console back without any warnings/succeed or something else.

Then I tried this command

```
sudo etherwake <my mac address> -D
```

Output:

```
 The target station address is 0:25:xx:xx:xx:xx.
 Packet is ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 25 xx xx xx xx 08 etc. etc.
 Sendto worked ! 116
```

Can someone help me?

This is my motherboard:
asrock-z68-extreme4-gen3

Oh, and yes! Boot from onboard LAN is enabled!! I checked this like 10 times for now.

Comment: @minitech: wouldn't this be a [unix.se] question? It *seems* more focused on the PC end, rather than the pi itself.

Comment: It's still more of a "computer setup" question than a programming question. I'd check that WakeOnLan is configured for the PC and THAT network card [and that the MAC address is right of course]

Comment: @DavidThomas: Could be, I just said "maybe" because that could be where the problem is. And Super User seems to cover all of that. But U&L works too :)

Comment: I tried this years ago.  I recall it using UDP but no worries re router and ports with that 'cos you're within your LAN anyway.    Have you enabled WakeOnLAN in your BIOS?

Comment: Yeess, 'boot from onboard lan is enabled' this setting is coming from my BIOS

Comment: Does it work for another computer? If so, you could monitor with wireshark what is happening and contrast the one where it works with the one where it doesn't work. Though you might not see much as it's only one way. Is your mains power switched on on that computer? Does your LAN have any lights? if so, perhaps there should be one light - a power light, though i'm not sure.

Comment: I cant use the answer button because I am new.

This is the answer:
<markedathome> Hopsy: if the pc can resume from that state with a keyboard or mouse movement, then wol should work, otherwise no. pc's still have power running through the boards which is why the motherboard will still have a led lit, so you don't destroy without switching the atx psu off/unplugging it.

Well, this did do the trick! The pc should go on standbye-mode/sleep-mode instead of shutdown (what I did). And I actually didnt knew this...

Comment: Interesting. You tagged Linux, but your screenshot is Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

Once you've got WOL enabled in the target system's BIOS, check that wake on LAN is enabled in its OS. In Linux, this can be done with following the command (on the target system):

```
sudo ethtool <NIC> | grep "Wake"
```

Where `<NIC>` is an interface name like `eth0`. The output should look something like the following:

```
Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g
```

If the output for `Supports Wake-on` doesn't contain the letter `g` either your hardware or driver is incompatible. If it does contain `g` and if the output for `Wake-on` contains `d` but not `g`, you should be able to enable WOL with the following command:

```
sudo ethtool -s <NIC> wol g
```

Note that this setting doesn't survive reboots, so you'll have to stash the command (minus the `sudo`) someplace where it will be executed on boot such as `/etc/network/interfaces` (which will also persist through `ifdown`/`ifup` cycles) or `/etc/rc.local`.

Now you should be able to wake the system from elsewhere with the `wakeonlan` command.

Reference:
[Ubuntu Help: Wake on LAN](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan#Enabling_WoL_in_the_NIC)

Comment: I wanted to add to check if the ethernet cable was a crossover cable (or if using a switch, hub, router, etc...), and make sure the receiving computer is actually getting the packet (via Wireshark or some other program).

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, what helped me at the end is passing the ip adresss with -i flag on wakeonlan.

For some reason it doesnt just work with mac address, but in combination with static IP I had on that machine I managed to wake it up